# How to delete a folder and all contents using a bat file in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, delete-file

I want to delete a folder with all files and subfolders using a bat file.

I have tried the following, but it is not working:

```
@DEL D:\PHP_Projects\testproject\Release\testfolder*.*
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 360, accepted):

```
@RD /S /Q "D:\PHP_Projects\testproject\Release\testfolder"
```

[Explanation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490990.aspx):

> Removes (deletes) a directory.
>
> ```
> RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
>
> /S      Removes all directories and files in the specified directory
>         in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory
>         tree.
>
> /Q      Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S
> ```

Comment: Can you please explain, why the @ flag befor RD ist needed and used? In the explanation there is only with rd.

Comment: @Hakikat41 it's the symbol for [reducing verbosity in batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21074863/50079). It doesn't affect the operation of the command itself, and doesn't do anything outside of batch files. Looking at the question, I imagine I put it there because the question itself has the `DEL` command with it included.

Answer (score 60):

1. `del /s /q c:\where ever the file is\*`
2. `rmdir /s /q c:\where ever the file is\`
3. `mkdir c:\where ever the file is\`

Comment: to delete all subfolders in a folder, use `*` in `for` : `for /d %G in ("D:\testfolder\*") do rd /s /q "%~G" `