# What does "@" mean in command line?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, syntax

I've found some execution command from Unreal Build Tool:

```
C:\VisualStudio\IDE2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe @"C:\MessageTag\Intermediate\Build\Win64\MessageTest\Development\DesktopPlatform\Module.DesktopPlatform.cpp.obj.response" /showIncludes
```

I tested a simple command line

```
cl @"F:\x\cc.txt"
```

with file content of cc.txt:

```
x.cpp
-Fe"y.exe"
```

The y.exe is created, and it seems that lines in the file "cc.txt" are chained into a string.

However if I simply type this:

```
@"F:\x\cc.txt"
```

in the command line, the text file is opened, neither showing file content nor execute the first line of the file content.

What does the "@" exactly do? Is there a documentation for it?

further question: This only works on cmd. Is there a Powerhsell equivalent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the at sign (@) in a batch file and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074863/what-is-the-at-sign-in-a-batch-file-and-what-does-it-do)

Comment: @user202729 do you really think I'm describing that thing?... Even though I can draw a conclusion on how it works base on my experiment, I wouldn't just set off without an exact behaviour description.

Comment: I didn't realize that your question also ask for usage in the middle of the command line. In this case @ has no special meaning, just read the docs of the command invoked.

Comment: possible duplicate , [What does the “@” symbol do in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363884/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-powershell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**When invoking `cl.exe`, a `@`-prefixed filename denotes a [*response file*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/at-specify-a-compiler-response-file)**, which is a text file that contains what would normally be command-line arguments, which "can be useful if your command-line arguments exceed 127 characters."

In PowerShell, where `@` is a metacharacter (a character with special meaning), you need to escape it as `` `@ `` or make it part of the quoted string, which should also work from `cmd.exe` / a batch file:

```bsh
# PowerShell

# Escape @ as `@
cl `@"F:\x\cc.txt"

#`# Alternatively, make @ part of the quoted string,
#   which also works from cmd.exe / a batch file.
cl "@F:\x\cc.txt"
```

---

The above use of `@`, as part of an *argument*, is specific to `cl.exe`, the program being invoked.

**By contrast, using `@` at the *start* of a command is (always) interpreted by the calling *shell* (`cmd.exe` or PowerShell)**:

- `cmd.exe`: `@` at the start of a command suppresses echoing that command before printing its output (it's like executing `echo off` beforehand, but scoped to the command at hand)

  - Therefore, executing `@"F:\x\cc.txt"` by itself  executes `"F:\x\cc.txt"` - which opens that file for editing - without echoing the command being executed first. (Note that without the `@` the command would only be echoed when executed from a batch file that does *not* start with `@echo off`.)
- PowerShell: `@` at the start of a statement can only initiate one of the following constructs:

  - a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules#here-strings) (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@` or `@'<newline>...<newline>'@`)
  - an [array-subexpression operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--) (`@(<command...>)`)
  - Therefore, trying to execute `@"F:\x\cc.txt"` by itself causes a syntax error.