# How to force delete a folder in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How to delete a folder in a batch file forcely ?

(Note- C:\Anything is a folder)

My code is:

```
@echo off
del C:\Anything
pause
```

But it's always asking-

```
Do you want to delete "C:\Anything" Y/N ?
```

I want that C:\Anything should delete with askimg for permision to do that !

Please help to optimize my problem !!!

Comment: Did you try `del /f /q C:\Anything`? You should look at `del /?` for options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a folder with all contents using a bat file in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331056/how-to-delete-a-folder-with-all-contents-using-a-bat-file-in-windows)

Answer (score 40):

Use the `rd` command to delete folders:

`rd /s /q "C:\My Folder\"`

**/s**: Deletes all files and folder from selected path.

**/q**: Suppress any message.

[The official docs are here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726055.aspx)

Comment: Considering that this is a site for questions and answers, and I found this result because it was specifically what I was looking for, don't you think it's kind of silly to tell people to read the documentation here?

Comment: what if I see "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." and don't know what process is holding that?

Comment: does not work with some occiped files, which can be delete via 'Delete' key

Answer (score 5):

```
set backupDir="D:\db_backup"

rmdir /s /q %backupDir%
```

here **/q** will eliminate that confirmation question.